# How do I make the rviz camera display accurate given the transform at the image timestamp?

Tags: rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, rviz shows a camera display with what appears to be the most recent transform available.  Instead, I need it to use tf at the image message stamp time (which is far enough back in time to have a tf available).  What do I need to change for that to happen?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10347/how-do-i-make-the-rviz-camera-display-accurate-given-the-transform-at-the-image-timestamp?/) by [kiwi](https://answers.ros.org/users/728/kiwi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When data arrives, rviz will always try to transform it to the fixed frame, given the latest available tf transform.

I understand you are looking at a camera image, with other features (e.g. laser scans) overlayed on the image, and you only want to show laser scans at the same time as the image timestamp. This behavior is not supported in rviz, and afaik it's not on the roadmap either.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0